# Bad Sql Grammar exception in JDBC spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am the getting

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select cid,
>   clinician-code, password, first-name, last-name from Clinician where
>   clinician-code= ?]; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'clinician' in 'field list'

error on the following code, You can also see the Table in the screen shot, except for cid all other attributes are VARCHAR(45)

[image: Clinician Table]

Row mapper class

```
public class CClinicianRowMapper implements RowMapper {

@Override
public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int line) throws SQLException {
    CClinicianResultSetExtractor extractor = new CClinicianResultSetExtractor();
    return extractor.extractData(rs);
}
```

}

Result Extractor Class
public class CClinicianResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

```
  @Override
  public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    CClinician clinician = new CClinician();
    clinician.setCid(rs.getLong("cid"));
    clinician.setClinicianCode(rs.getString("clinician-code"));
    clinician.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
    clinician.setFirstName(rs.getString("first-name"));
    return clinician;
  }
```

}

Class for selecting data from table

```
public List<CClinician> findClinician(CClinician _clinician) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    try
    {
    return select.query("select cid, clinician-code, password, first-name, last-name from Clinician where clinician-code= ?",
            new Object[] {_clinician.getClinicianCode()}, new CClinicianRowMapper());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a dash in the column names, you need to escape them with back ticks.

```
"SELECT cid, `clinician-code`, password, `first-name`, `last-name` 
     FROM Clinician 
     WHERE `clinician-code` = ?"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Exception is gone but still its returning nothing in query though the data is there in the table

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old thread, but hopefully anyone stumbling across this question will find this answer useful.

I was getting the same exception in my spring app.  Based on the output, I thought I had a syntax issue with my query.  It turns out that I actually had a syntax error in my mapper method.  I came across this issue because I originally created my Product class with different field names than the column names.

```
public class ProductMapper implements RowMapper<Product> {
public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
  Product product = new Product();
  product.setProduct_id(rs.getInt("product_id"));  //was id.  was causing BadSqlGrammarException
  product.setProduct_name(rs.getString("product_name")); //was name.  was causing BadSqlGrammarException
  product.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
  product.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));
  return product;
   }
}
```

Once I made the above changes (my fields are named product_id and product_name), my app worked correctly.  Just remember that any changes you make to column names or java fields should be made not only to your query statements, but also to your mapper method as well.  I see that the OP did this correctly, but I thought it was worth reiterating.  I hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: yes you are correct, currently i am facing the same problem and before going through this post I guess it is happening because of the mapper.

Comment: This was exactly the issue I had. Thank you so much!

Comment: you saved me a lot of hassle, thank you. Hard to think of the mapper when your focus is on the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i hade table name wrong in my java code!!

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a missing field name in my sql schema while my Class had the field declared.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query syntax properly for missing ; or extra comma (,) . 'Bad SQL Grammar Exception' is related only to syntactical  mistake in Sql queries.
I was getting same error in following code while working on Spring JDBC:

```
String query= "update student set name=?, city=?, where id=?"; // due to extra comma after city=?,
```

Changed code to

```
String query= "update student set name=? city=?, where id=?";
```

Error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
String query = "update student set name=?, city=?, where id=?";
```

into

```
String query = "update student set name=?, city=? where id=?";
```

and it resolved
I used comma after name